# Labels missing off x Axis in amCharts

Tags: javascript, html, amcharts, amcharts4

It seems like even number counted labels (2, 4 etc) are being hidden in my chart.

Unsure why as I haven't specifically set the hide these anywhere in the code.

**Demo**:

```js
        var chart = am4core.create("dataChart", am4charts.XYChart);

        chart.data = [{
            "xValue": "Q1",
            "yValue": 6
        }, {
            "xValue": "Q2",
            "yValue": 7
        }, {
            "xValue": "Q3",
            "yValue": 3
        }, {
            "xValue": "Q4",
            "yValue": 2
        }, {
            "xValue": "Q5",
            "yValue": 9
        }];

        /* Create axes */
        var theXAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
        theXAxis.dataFields.category = "xValue";

        /* Create value axis */
        var theYAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
        theYAxis.renderer.labels.template.disabled = true;

        /* Create series */
        var series1 = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
        series1.dataFields.valueY = "yValue";
        series1.dataFields.categoryX = "xValue";
        series1.bullets.push(new am4charts.CircleBullet());
        series1.tooltipText = "{valueY} / 10";
        series1.fill = "#2c3e96";
        series1.fillOpacity = .3;
        series1.stroke = "#4967fa";
        
        /* Create a cursor */
        chart.cursor = new am4charts.XYCursor();
```

```css
#dataChart{
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>

<div id="dataChart"></div>
```

Edit:

I can see in the demo above,  it works (Q2 and Q4 labels are hidden for me everywhere else).

This [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h0x74bvt/) here however, showcases what I'm experiencing.

What I'm seeing:

[image]

Comment: It gets cropped due to the width. Make the chart wider and the labels should reappear.

Answer (score 5):

The label density is controlled by the `minGridDistance` property in the axis renderer, as mentioned [in the documentation](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/axes/positioning-axis-elements/#Setting_the_density_of_the_the_grid_labels). You'll want to set this to a smaller value if you want to show more labels.

```
theXAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 30; //adjust as needed
```

Demo below:

```js
var chart = am4core.create("dataChart", am4charts.XYChart);

chart.data = [{
  "xValue": "Q1",
  "yValue": 6
}, {
  "xValue": "Q2",
  "yValue": 7
}, {
  "xValue": "Q3",
  "yValue": 3
}, {
  "xValue": "Q4",
  "yValue": 2
}, {
  "xValue": "Q5",
  "yValue": 9
}];

/* Create axes */
var theXAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
theXAxis.dataFields.category = "xValue";
theXAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 30;
/* Create value axis */
var theYAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
theYAxis.renderer.labels.template.disabled = true;

/* Create series */
var series1 = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
series1.dataFields.valueY = "yValue";
series1.dataFields.categoryX = "xValue";
series1.bullets.push(new am4charts.CircleBullet());
series1.tooltipText = "{valueY} / 10";
series1.fill = "#2c3e96";
series1.fillOpacity = .3;
series1.stroke = "#4967fa";

/* Create a cursor */
chart.cursor = new am4charts.XYCursor();
```

```css
#dataChart {
  width: 300px;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>

<div id="dataChart"></div>
```

Comment: unimaginable but solved my issue.... thank you [me wondering if I should do a PhD in amcharts documentation]